# How to delete the "..." folder in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, delete-file

I have created the uncreateable "..." (three dots) folder in Windows with this code:

```
mkdir \\?\C:\Users\User\Desktop\...
```

But if I try to delete it, it asks to me if I want to "Permanently Delete My Desktop", When I click on yes, it just crashes explorer, but doesn't delete the "..." folder!

I already tried also with cmd:

```
rem ...
del ...
delete ...
```

But it never worked!

Comment: `rem` is for comments, `del` deletes files, same for `erase`, and there is no `delete` command; what you are looking for is `rmdir` or `rd` (type each command followed by `/?` into a Command Prompt window to learn its usage)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a directory. Not a file.

```
rmdir \\?\C:\Users\User\Desktop\...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove it with

```
rmdir .\...\
```

This is the simplest way: No UNC nor full paths.

Comment: Trailing spaces and dots are only stripped from the final path component, so adding a trailing slash works for a directory name. OTOH, for a regular file, ``del .\...\`` will fail as an invalid name. The system finds a regular file, but the trailing slash requires a directory. So in general a "\\?\" verbatim path is required. In CMD, you can use `del "\\?\%CD%\..."` if the file is in the current directory, which should always work because CMD doesn't allow the current directory to be a UNC path.

Answer (score -1):

7-zip helped me. It allows you to rename such a folder, after which it can be deleted.